# Referencing a belonged_to items owner in Rails / ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets say I have a Person model and a Opinion model.  Opinions belong to Person, a Person has many Opinions.  Some people are shy.

I am trying to find a set of opinions where the person is 'not shy' or something along those lines.  Is there a way to do this that does not involve finding all people who are not shy and then finding those people's opinions?  I would like to do something like the pseudo-code below:

`@opinions = Opinion.all.where_owner_person('shy = false')`

this might be something obvious I have missed, but I can't seem to come up with the right phrasing in my searches to catch the answer.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@opinions = Opinion.joins(:person).where(:people => { :shy => false })
```

[ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) has some more examples.

Comment: looks like joins needs the singular and where needs the plural so final working is like: `@opinions = Opinion.joins(:person).where(:people => { :shy => false })
`